# Event object manual-reset, wrong thread synchronization

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, events, synchronization

I'm approaching to C Windows programming in particular threads, concurrency and synchronization.
To experiment, I'm writing a C program that accepts N parameters.
Each parameter indicates a path to a file system directory tree and the program has to compare the content of all directories to decide whether all directories have the same content or not.
The main runs a "reading" thread for each parameter while a single "comparison" thread compares the name of all the entries found. For each file/directory found, "reading" threads synchronize themselves by activating the "comparison" thread.

I wrote the program with `Semaphore` objects and now I'm trying with `Event` objects.
The idea is to use `N Events auto-reset` and a `single Event manual-reset`.

The N events are used by the N "reading" threads to signal the "comparison" thread which is in `WaitForMultipleObjects` for an `INFINITE` time. When all the signals are available, it starts comparing the entry and then it performs a `SetEvent()` for the manual-reset object.
The "reading" threads wait for this set and then Reset the event and continue working with the next entry.

Some code for the N reading threads:

```
void ReadingTraverseDirectory(LPTSTR StartPathName, DWORD i) {

    //variables and some work

    do {

        //take the next entry and put it in current_entry;
        gtParams[it].entry = current_entry;           //global var for comparison

        SetEvent(glphReadingEvent[i]);                  //signal the comparison thread

        WaitForSingleObject(ghComparisonEvent, INFINITE); //wait signal to restart working
        ResetEvent(ghComparisonEvent);               //reset the event

        if (current_entry == TYPE_DIR) {
            ReadingTraverseDirectory(current_entry, i); //recur to explor the next dir
        }

    } while (FindNextFile(SearchHandle, &FindData)); //while there are still entries

//
return;
}
```

Some code for the comparison thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI CompareThread(LPVOID arg) { 

     while (entries are equal){

        WaitForMultipleObjects(N, glphReadingEvent, TRUE, 1000);

        for (r = 0; r < nworkers - 1; r++){
            if (_tcscmp(entries) != 0){
                 //entries are different. exit and close.
            }
        }

        SetEvent(ghComparisonEvent);

     }

}
```

The problem:
Sometimes it happens that one reading thread is able to work without respecting the synchro with other threads. If I put a `printf()` or `Sleep(1)` -between Wait and Set of the comparison thread-, the program works perfectly.

My opinion:
I think the manual-reset Event is not safe for this kind of (barrier)synchronization.
A reading thread may be too fast in `ResetEvent()` and if the scheduler slows down other threads, it is possible that some of them risk to stay blocked while the one which performed the Reset is able to continue its work.
However if this is the case, the comparison thread should block itself on `WaitingForMultipleObjects` causing a deadlock... actually there is no deadlock but 1 thread is able to cycle more times respect to others.
What I'm trying to understand is why a simple Sleep(1) can solve the issue. Is it matter of scheduling or wrong implementation of synchronization?

Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to mention glphReadingEvent are auto-reset. From windows dev-center I read "An event object whose state remains signaled until a single waiting thread is released, at which time the system automatically sets the state to nonsignaled."